# MOSFET is messing up the voltage seen on the drain, when it should be either an open or closed circuit

Tags: mosfet

I have this eFuse which uses voltage dividers to turn on an enable pin, and also set the proper voltage threshold for over-voltage protection. This circuit works just fine on its own, but I wanted to add a method to disable the enable pin through a watchdog chip. To do this, I've connected fets in parallel, which connect to the enable pin so that it can pull the enable pin LOW when I want to disable it. The voltage divider voltages should all go to ground, while the main Vin supply isn't affected. I've used FETs many times to trigger pins but this is the first time I'm having a serious problem and I've crossed every T I could find that was obvious to me. Looking for some suggestions on how I may troubleshoot this...

I've included a partial schematic below. R48 is just a solder bridge that I use to electrically disconnect the watchdog's control from the eFuse for testing. When it is open, the eFuse works just fine and I see the proper 1V at the Enable pin that I'm supposed to. Soon as I short R48 I now see 560mV at the enable PIN.

The watchdog starts off by enabling the EN pin of the eFuse, but after 5 minutes will go LOW. When it's supposed to go LOW, instead of seeing 0V, I see 320mV at the drain of U13. U13 is supposed to pull it to 0V.

U13 and U14 are both n-fets DMG1012UW-7.

TLDR: I should see 1V at the enable pin when U13 is OFF, but I see 560mV. When U13 is ON, I should see 0V at the enable pin, but I see 320mV.[image]

Update: I measured the gate of U13 with an oscilloscope and I'm seeing a bit of noise, here is a photo. The scale is 100mV and looks like I'm getting about 25mV of noise. Not sure if that would make a huge difference.

[image]

Comment: Please supply a more complete circuit and provide data sheet links to the main silicon items.

Comment: Measure gate-source voltage on U13 (why "U"?) and VDS.  If you have >> Vth on Vgs and your FET isn't pulling to ground measure the drain current to be sure there's not something broken downstream.  If the drain current is reasonable, replace the FET.

Comment: Are the power supplies correct?

Comment: Unfortunately for confidentiality reasons, I can't provide a more complete schematic. This is the datasheet for the N-FETs: https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMG1012UW.pdf

This is the datasheet for the eFuse: https://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=10&gotoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2FTPS25942A

The U designation is what came with the offthe shelf schematic and footprint I got off of UltraLibrarian. Vgs is between 0.5-1V and I def see 0V at the gate, I tried to short gate to ground ontop of this just to make sure and nothing changed.

Comment: The power supplies are correct yes, 5V is 4.98V and 3.3V is 3.291V, so no very much out of spec.

Comment: I added a photo of the gnd pin of U13 as seen on my oscilloscope.

Comment: "U" as a designator isn't really *wrong*, but it's certainly weird. Transistors are always either Q or, occasionally for MOSFETs, M. U is used for ICs and anything else without a standard designator letter.

Comment: The MC74HC... requires a 5V supply, not 3.3V.

Answer (score 0):

"When you have eliminated all which is impossible then whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth."

I decided to try and solder a new board but only populate the portion of the circuit that has these FETs on it, just in case there was something wrong with the manufacturing of the first one. It still didn't work, so I ended up checking the pads and the source and drain where flipped. I got the library file from Snapeda and whom ever made the library did it wrong. The symbol is correct, but the pads on the layout where wrong. I did some Macgyvering and flipped the pads on the PCB and everything works fine now.

I had assumed whom ever did the library did it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that U13 doesn't sink the current completely for two possible reasons.
1/ The 3.3V current is not enough to turn on completely the U13 FET, especially as it's impeded by the 1M resistor. I recommend using 5V at the gate of U13.
2/ The gate of U14 is not at zero V and there is still some leakage. ut theorically it shouldn't be.